# I need an SQL query to find all the words you can make with a set of letters, including up to two blank tiles

Tags: java, android, sql, regex, discrete-mathematics

I have a database table called dictionary currently with the following fields for all dictionary entries:

```
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_UID = "_id_";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WORD = "word";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WORD = "wordSorted";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WORD_LENGTH = "length";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_A = "count_A";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_B = "count_B";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_C = "count_C";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_D = "count_D";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_E = "count_E";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_F = "count_F";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_G = "count_G";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_H = "count_H";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_I = "count_I";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_J = "count_J";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_K = "count_K";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_L = "count_L";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_M = "count_M";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_N = "count_N";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_O = "count_O";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_P = "count_P";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_Q = "count_Q";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_R = "count_R";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_S = "count_S";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_T = "count_T";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_U = "count_U";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_V = "count_V";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_W = "count_W";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_X = "count_X";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_Y = "count_Y";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COUNT_Z = "count_Z";
```

I want to be able to search for instance test* and find all the words that can be made out of "t" "e" "s" "t" and an wildcard, such as words like "tests" (s is wildcard), "setts" (s is a wildcard), "set", "tet" "es" "te", "best" (b is a wildcard), etc... Anything you can make with any combination of those letters.

I have tried methods like this, but this example only finds the four letter words without a wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE 

count_E=1 AND
count_S=1 AND
count_T=2 

SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE  length <=4
```

This produces:

```
"137075"    "sett"  "estt"
"145808"    "stet"  "estt"
"153675"    "test"  "estt"
"153851"    "tets"  "estt"
```

Now, I know, this is kind of a dicreet math problem at heart.

Here is how I can get all 5 letter words with one blank space and all the letters provided in the last query:

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE 

count_E=1 AND
count_S=1 AND
count_T=2 

INTERSECT 
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE  length <=5
```

Results:

```
"97705"     "netts" "enstt"
"137075"    "sett"  "estt"
"145250"    "state" "aestt"
"145808"    "stet"  "estt"
"152303"    "taste" "aestt"
"152333"    "tates" "aestt"
"152632"    "teats" "aestt"
"153361"    "tents" "enstt"
"153675"    "test"  "estt"
"153676"    "testa" "aestt"
"153733"    "testy" "estty"
"153769"    "teths" "ehstt"
"153851"    "tets"  "estt"
"153874"    "texts" "esttx"
"156575"    "totes" "eostt"
"157952"    "trets" "erstt"
"172060"    "yetts" "estty"
```

However, I'd have to go through all iterations of combinations of letters to get all the hiding sub-words in there... Can anyone help me think of a more elegant approach to finding anagrams and sub-words from a query and up to two wildcards? I am also aware that you can use REGEXP in SQL, so that might be a way. I don't know at this point, and I'm taking this problem to the hive...

Is there a query, or series of queries, or intersections, joins, etc... that would help me solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
I think I may have stumbled upon this, but am not sure if it is working correctly. Any help would be appreciated:

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE 
(
count_E<=1 AND
count_S<=1 AND
count_T<=1 
)
INTERSECT SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE length =(count_E+count_S+count_T+1)     ORDER BY length
```

The +1 is to account for one blank space. For two, I'm thinking of just doing a +2, etc... +0 would be just those letters, and anything you can make from them.

Comment: I don't think you can use REGEXP in sqlite.

Comment: Yes, you can. I've tried and it works. There's the REGEXP command that works in my SQLiteBrowser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must perform the following, put together a concatenation of all the fields of the table as follows:

```
concatenacion = "(_id||' '||Desc_art||' '||Nom_proveedor||' '||marca) like '"+resultado+"'" +
            "OR (_id||' '||Nom_proveedor||' '||marca||' '||Desc_art) like '"+resultado+"'" +
            "OR (marca||' '||Nom_proveedor||' '||Desc_art||' '||_id) like '"+resultado+"'" +
            "OR (marca||' '||Nom_proveedor||' '||_id||' '||Desc_art) like '"+resultado+"'" +
            "OR (Desc_art||' '||Nom_proveedor||' '||marca||' '||_id) like '"+resultado+"'" +
            "OR (Desc_art||' '||_id||' '||Nom_proveedor||' '||marca) like '"+resultado+"'";
```

Then make your request and in the WHERE clause must put your conecatenacion for example:

```
cursor=bd.rawQuery("select _id, Desc_art, cant_art, Desc_bulto, precio"+getDefaultNroLista(codcliente)+", tiene_imagen,marca from listas_precios where "+concatenacion+" ORDER BY Desc_art ASC", null);
```

I work very well for me, hope it serves

Comment: these variables are for example, you would have to adapt this to your problem. greetings